# Объединение / смешивание двух массивов

Tags: java, массивы, объединение

Начал изучать java и получил следующее задание:

Написать класс, который содержит две целочисленных переменных `а` и `б` со значениями, к примеру, `1234` и `5678` соответственно.

Реализовать метод этого класса, который возвращает новое число `в` со значением `15263748`, полученным из `а` и `б`.

Как я предположил сначала, можно из этих двух переменных сделать два строковых массива и смешать их нужным образом.

```java
String s = "" + a;
String[] arr = s.split("");
System.out.println(arr);
```

На этом у меня все встало.

В пошаговой отладке eclipse - массив `arr` строковый и получает значения `[1,2,3,4]` и второй массив, соответственно, `[5,6,7,8]`.

На выходе же `sysout` выдает что то типа `[Ljava.lang.String;@5fcfe4b2`,
и как то дальше совсем не идет, может быть я с самого начала не в том направлении мыслю?

Comment: а использовать грязный хак типа 

  return 15256836 + a + b не подходит? Насколько я понимаю, условию это не противоречит

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкатенировать два числа вы можете разными способами,
в первую очередь такими:

1. Перевести числа в строки, объединить строки, перевести результат назад в число;
2. С помощью простого арифметического преобразования. Отдельные цифры числа выделаются в этом случае путём деления на 10**n, где n постепенно сдвигается от 0 и выше.

Comment: 'public String abc (int a, int b){
  
     String str = Integer.toString(a);
     String [] arr = str.split(""); 
     String str1 = Integer.toString(b);
     String [] arrs = str1.split(""); 
     String c = arr[0]+arrs[0]+arr[1]+arrs[1]+arr[2]+arrs[2]+arr[3]+arrs[3];
          
  return c;
 }'
я сделал примерно так, на сколько это верно ?(Товарищ модератор а где можно глянуть как красиво оформлять коментарии и ответы ?)

Comment: @tumakov-a: так а зачем разбивать строку на символы? я не совсем понимаю, в чём тут смысл

Comment: мне на выходе нужно получить число 15263748, а не просто строка1 + строка 2, я разбиваю строку на символы складываю их в массив, а потом в третьей строке выставляю нужный порядок, потом перевожу ее в интовую переменную. Увы но мои знания пока не позволяют найти другое решение ((((

Comment: @tumakov-a: стоп, я неправильно понял задание, я не заметил, что символы нужно перемешать. Тогдой мой ответ невер, я удаляю его

Comment: Не могу удалить, потому что его уже приняли. Уберите, пожалуйста, зелёную галочку, я тогда смогу удалить мой ответ

Comment: 1 пункт вашего ответа подтолкнул меня к нужному выходу. А именно последняя его часть, "перевести результат назад в число;"

Comment: @tumakov-a: Хорошо, я тогда немного перепишу ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
private long concatIntegers(int a, int b){
    String tempA = "" + a, tempB = "" + b;
    boolean isFirstStringLonger = tempA.length() > tempB.length();
    final int len = isFirstStringLonger ? tempB.length() : tempA.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(tempA.charAt(i)).append(tempB.charAt(i));
    }
    sb.append(isFirstStringLonger ? tempA.substring(len) : tempB.substring(len));
    return Long.parseLong(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. переводим числа в строки
2. делим строки на массивы символов
3. идём циклом по массивам и собираем результат
4. выводим что получилось

---

```java
int a = 1234;
int b = 5678;

char[] aArr = String.valueOf(a).toCharArray();
char[] bArr = String.valueOf(b).toCharArray();

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result.append(aArr[i]).append(bArr[i]);
}

System.out.println(result.toString()); // 15263748
```